# PostgreSQL 11 Shared Memory Error: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.XXXXXXXX": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-11

Shared Memory files getting deleted some time (~15 hours) in Postgres 11

```
2019-07-09 08:46:41 CDT [] [6723]: [1-1] user=,db=,e=58P01 ERROR:  could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.291691635": No such file or directory
2019-07-09 08:46:41 CDT [] [6722]: [1-1] user=,db=,e=58P01 ERROR:  could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.291691635": No such file or directory
2019-07-09 08:46:41 CDT [10.40.0.204(60550)] [13880]: [1-1] user=user_name,db=db_name,e=58P01 ERROR:  could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.291691635": No such file or directory
2019-07-09 08:46:41 CDT [10.40.0.204(60550)] [13880]: [2-1] user=user_name,db=db_name,e=58P01 CONTEXT:  parallel worker
2019-07-09 08:46:41 CDT [10.40.0.204(60550)] [13880]: [3-1] user=user_name,db=db_name,e=58P01 STATEMENT:  WITH overall_reviewed AS (SQL Query)
```

**GCP VM Config**

```
CPU: 4
RAM: 16 GB
 OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

kernel shared memory setting shared

```
kernel.shmmax=8589934592
kernel.shmall=2097152
```

**postgresql.config**

```
max_connections = 500
shared_buffers = 4GB
effective_cache_size = 12GB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 4194kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

During startup: no errors/warnings
After ~15 hours some of the shared memory files is getting deleted, I'm doubting is there any other process deleting files in "`/dev/shm`" ?

Not sure what is the root cause

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I randomly run into this issue on my OpenBSD postgresql setup also. Every week or two it will randomly occur on one of the clients connected to the database. postgresql is still functional when this occurs, and just restarting the client is enough for things to resume working for another week or so.

Comment: making dynamic_shared_memory_type = none in postgresql.conf did solve the issue.

Comment: Any new solutions to this problem @n1000 ?  It seems that `"none"` is no longer an option for `dynamic_shared_memory_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

making dynamic_shared_memory_type = none in postgresql.conf did solve the issue.

Comment: It works in postgres@10 but not at @12 anymore, I  used `mmap` instead and now it's working

Answer (score 4):

Got the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL 11 and after some more research i have found a solution for us. The error occured when the backup user, which ist he same user as the PG service user, logs into the system. The following Link describes that the storeage under /dev/shm where deleted when a user logs in to the system (same user). So our solution was to change the following:

```
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

added the Line

```
RemoveIPC=no
```

and restart the service

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

Sources:

https://www.postgresql-archive.org/systemd-deletes-shared-memory-segment-in-dev-shm-Postgresql-NNNNNN-td5883507.html

https://superuser.com/questions/1117764/why-are-the-contents-of-dev-shm-is-being-removed-automatically

Answer (score 1):

Met the same issue.....when I have opened two sqldeveloper with the same user account, one of them is my remote session which I completely forgot to close the session.

I was doing some aggregation operators like count(*) or max(...), and the error on both. And the error is similar:

> ERROR: could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.798235387":
> No such file or directory   Where: parallel worker

Solution? I killed the remote session.... XD
And life is peaceful and happy again :D

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and it turned out that someone set postgres user's UID bigger than 1000 (which means that `postgres` user was no longer a system account). And, as said [here](https://superuser.com/a/1179962/1097408):

```
After hours of searching and reading, I found the culprit.
It's a setting for systemd. The /etc/systemd/logind.conf contains default configuration options, with each of them commented out.
The RemoveIPC option is set to yes by default. That option tells systemd to clean up interprocess communication (IPC) for "user accounts" who aren't logged in.

================================================
This does not affect "system accounts"
================================================
```